# Firebase store email's verification status in database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I need to store email's verification status info in database in firebase. For example when an user create an email/password account with uid="001", I will create a node in database: '001':{emailverified: false}. And then when they verify this email I will update the node '001':{emailverified: true}

I tried by creating custom email action handlers. But the problem is that when user click the link to verify his email, I can not get the user's uid from the oobCode. So I can not find a way to update email's verification in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you want to store this information in your database as Firebase already stores it for you.... but you can do something like this to get the value of the email verification. I'd just check it when they attempt to login and update the value in your database. Again not sure why you want to store this.

```
func login() {
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: {(user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            // alert user of the error 
        }
        if user != nil && user!.isEmailVerified {
            // upload true to your database         
        }
        else if user != nil && !user!.isEmailVerified {
            // upload false
        }    
    })
}
```

You might also be able to use:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser.isEmailVerified // not sure if this works
```

Comment: I need to create a form for registering an event. An user can attend this event by going to my website and signup, but they can also fill their email in the paper form and we will create an account for them (with their email and default password is 123456). And I want to list all user that are not verified in order to delete this account when needed to let other people can attend my event (only emails that is  can go to the event because our capacity are only 250 people)

Comment: Where is the property "isEmailVerified" stored in the Firebase server? I can't find it in the Authentication Users table.

Comment: Firebase stores this value internally. It is not stored in your database by default, just like the UID's.